# Verify digital signature within system32/drivers folder

Tags: c++, winapi, crypt, winverifytrust

I've spent all night researching this without a solution.

I'm trying to verify the digital signature of a file in the drives folder (C:\Windows\System32\drivers*.sys) pick whatever one you want.  I know that the code is correct because if you move the file from that folder to C:\ the test works.

`WinVerifyTrust` gives error 80092003
http://pastebin.com/nLR7rvZe

`CryptQueryObject` gives error 80092009
http://pastebin.com/45Ra6eL4

What's the deal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

0x80092003 = CRYPT_E_FILE_ERROR = An error occurred while reading or writing to the file.

0x80092009 = CRYPT_E_NO_MATCH = No match when trying to find the object.

I'm guessing you're running on a 64-bit machine and WOW64 file system redirection is redirecting you to syswow64\drivers, which is empty.  You can disable redirection with [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This does seem to solve the problem - though I am running into additional difficulties.  Still investigating this, but some files fail with one but succeed with the other.

Answer (score 4):

if you right click and view properties of file can you see a digital signature? most likely your file is part of a catalogue and you need to use the catalogue API to extract the cert from cert DB and verify it.